# Flutter Web: Routing URL without Stacking?

Tags: flutter-web

I am trying to fix the app bar and just change the content inside the Scaffold. However, I could not find a way to just change the route URL without stacking up. That opens up a new page and covers the `Home` widget.

```
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBarWidget(),
    body: HomeScreen(context: context), <----- changing just this to set different URL
  ),
```

Is it possible to just change the widget of the Scaffold's body while also changing the url of the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Material(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
      '/': (ctx) => Widget1(),
      }
    );
```

Inside Widget1 Scafold body add following Widget for navigation in web and app

```
Navigator(
    initialRoute: "two/home",
    onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      WidgetBuilder builder;
      switch (settings.name) {
        case "two/home":
          builder = (BuildContext context) => HomeOfTwo();
          break;
        case "two/nextpage":
          builder = (BuildContext context) => PageTwoOfTwo();
          break;
      }
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
    },
  );
```

This might work